# PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME doesn't seem to work in Jinja2 Flask Template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, facebook-login

I am implementing FB login on my webapp here [www.glifft.com](https://www.glifft.com.) but I can't seem to get the redirect right. The redirect after logging in should be to https://www.glifft.com/myglifft. I'm using the url_for() function in Flask in the Jinja2 template to generate this URL. But I can't seem to generate with the https in front. It always generates as http.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function getuserDetails(accessToken) {
   FB.api('/me',{ locale: 'en_US', fields: 'name, email' }, function(response) {
         $.ajax({
             url: "/register",
             type: "POST",
             data: {
                     name: response.name,
                     email: response.email,
                     login_provider : "Facebook",
                     access_token: accessToken
                 },

                 success: function(response) {
                     location.href = "{{ url_for('myglifft', _external=True) }}";
                     console.log(location.href)
                 },
                 error: function(response) {
                     alert("Please check your facebook privacy settings.");
                     console.log(response)
                 }
         });
     });
```

The location.href function keeps resolving to http://www.glifft.com. Even though in my config I have

```
PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME = 'https'
```

The error I get in chrome is this:

[image: Chrome Console Error]

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.glifft.com/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.glifft.com/myglifft'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

It seems like this should work. Why is the PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME flag not working????

Answer (score 5):

The PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME seems to be buggy for me too.
If you have very few url_for calls, the passing _scheme='https' can be considered. So, the line would be,

```
location.href = "{{ url_for('myglifft', _external=True, _scheme='https') }}";
```

Answer (score 2):

`url_for` respects `PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME` **only if** you are not inside a request context, if you are in a view function, it will always use `request.url`

here is someone's attempt to fix the documentation for that:
https://github.com/untitaker/flask/commit/b49074eb6b19d8f5fdb3301a6e50f11845dd530d

if you add `url_for(view, _external=True, _scheme='https')` it will do the trick